# Adding child Xelement if it doesnt exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have few solutions on how to do this, but I was wondering if there is a neat way to do this.

```
<Project>
    <Test>
        <Name value="zero">
        <Name value="One">
        <Name value="Two">
    </Test>
</Project>
```

Now, I have access to testElement. I want to add new child XElement to it, only when it doesn't exist.

What I am currently doing is this. This is only sample code I am typing which is equivalent to what I am doing, so pardon me for minor mistakes.

```
XElement element = (from item
                    in testElement.Elements("name")
                    where item.Attribute("value") == "zero"
                    select item).SingleOrDefault();

if (element == null)
{
    testElement.add(newElement);
}
```

Is there is a better way to do this? Maybe a simpler check?

Comment: you have invalid xml, `Name` node is not closed. `testElement.Elements("Name").Any()` should work as well. It's not quite obvious what you want to achieve - do you want to add node if **none** exist or **specific node with exact attribute** doesn't exist

Comment: define the *neat way* .

Comment: L.B : I have updated the question. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @user3606175 Does your current code work and you're looking for improvements, or are you trying to figure out how to make it work?

Comment: It works for now. I just thought maybe I wrote too much code for something that could be achieved in simple code.

Answer (score 1):

you may perhaps use XPath extensions available via `using System.Xml.XPath;` to avoid lengthy LINQ, this is pretty simpler and easy

example

```
    XElement element = testElement.XPathSelectElement("Name[@value='zero']");

    if (element == null)
    {
        testElement.add(newElement);
    }
```

XPath `Name[@value='zero']` in the example above says that you are looking for an element named `Name` which has an attribute `@` named `value` and has the value of `zero`. so the linq in the question is reduced to on single `XPathSelectElement` and rest remains same.

optional, this is just a rewrite of above code

```
    if (testElement.XPathSelectElement("Name[@value='zero']") == null)
    {
        testElement.add(newElement);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an `XAttribute` to a string, so you probably are not getting the result you want.

```
item.Attribute("value") == "zero"
```

Try changing it to:

```
(string)item.Attribute("value") == "zero"
```

This converts the attribute to a string before the comparison.